# unable to create a service

Tags: android

I have a music player application and untill now, it was working smoothly.

So, i learnt about `Android Focus` from android documentation and i thought i would try this on my app for learning purposes.

App: minimum api level :`16`; Maximum:`26`;

I basically implemented the `AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener` in my service class.

In it i included this code:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=26){
            mAudioFocusRequest = new AudioFocusRequest.Builder(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN)
                    .setAudioAttributes(mAudioAttributes)
                    .setAcceptsDelayedFocusGain(true)
                    .setOnAudioFocusChangeListener(this)
                    .build();
            int res = mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(mAudioFocusRequest);
            synchronized(mFocusLock) {
                if (res == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_FAILED) {
                    mPlaybackNowAuthorized = false;
                } else if (res == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
                    mPlaybackNowAuthorized = true;
                    playSong();
                } else if (res == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_DELAYED) {
                    mPlaybackDelayed = true;
                    mPlaybackNowAuthorized = false;
                }
            }

        } else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<26){
            int result = 0;
            if (mAudioManager != null) {
                result = mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(this,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
            }

            if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
                mPlaybackNowAuthorized = true;
                playSong();
            }

        }
```

My `onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange)` looks something like this:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<26){
            //<26 code
        }else {
           //26 and above api level
    }
```

I tried implementing `audiofocus` in my application and this is how i did it. The issue is when i try to run my app now , it gives me this error

> unable to create a service

What's the problem with it? i think i read the documentation clearly.

Am i missing out something?

**Update:**

Removing the below code does make it work

```
 else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<26){
        int result = 0;
        if (mAudioManager != null) {
            result = mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(this,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
        }

        if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
            mPlaybackNowAuthorized = true;
            playSong();
        }
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
     12-18 16:27:47.740 30183-30183/com.example.tilak.imusicplay E/AndroidRuntime: 
12-18 16:27:47.740 30183-30183/com.example.tilak.imusicplay E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.tilak.imusicplay, PID: 30183
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.example.tilak.imusicplay.MusicService: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2920)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:153)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1458)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at com.example.tilak.imusicplay.MusicService.playSong(MusicService.java:239)
                                                                                  at com.example.tilak.imusicplay.MusicService.initMusicPlayer(MusicService.java:115)
                                                                                  at com.example.tilak.imusicplay.MusicService.onCreate(MusicService.java:66)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2910)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:153) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1458) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629) 
12-18 16:27:47.742 30183-30183/com.example.tilak.imusicplay E/MQSEventManagerDelegate: failed to get MQSService.
```

[Whole Class Code](https://pastebin.com/xVvfxPCm)

Comment: *What's the problem with it?* - you are supposed to tell us. We are not wizards who can magically guess problems

Comment: I can't figure out, one thing that i saw was that as i comment out `else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<26){
            int result = 0;
            if (mAudioManager != null) {
                result = mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(this,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
            }

            if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
                mPlaybackNowAuthorized = true;
                playSong();
            }` this part , it does work.

Comment: I have no clue what you are saying. You have some code and it works, or maybe not, perhaps you have an error, no clue. You are supposed to tell us what your issue is

Comment: there is no need to be rude and ignorant. I tried impementing `audiofocus` in my application and this is how i did it. The issue is when i try to run my app now , it gives me this error `unable to create a service`  what is so hard to understand?

Comment: I'm not ignorant, you posted half a question. I have to comment twice before you even tell what the error is, and there is no stacktrace either. Please read [ask] and provide some detail

Comment: @TimCastelijns does it help now? let me post the stack trace too

Comment: @TimCastelijns please consider my question again.

Comment: I don't understand. You don't know what a nullpointerexception is, or is there another issue?

Comment: `brother` , `Song songPlay=songs.get(songposn);`: this is the line that throws that exception. Why did it do ? because it didn't create an instance of the service class in the starting place.Hence coming to the same point again. I know what is a null pointer exception is

Comment: @TimCastelijns i dont think there was a point to downvote it and close it.. :)

Comment: it is not for you to decide how other people vote on your question. Good luck fixing your issue. I suggest you fix that NPE before continuing.

Comment: i will through my bounty tommorow , lets see if it helps. Thanks for the help though. i appreciate it.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: @StephenC seriously downvote? The service didn't get created in the first place, hence the error

Comment: Yes.  Downvote.  This is a classical NPE, and the solution is self-evident; i.e. you haven't done adequate research.  (Starting with ... not reading the stacktrace properly ...)  Furthermore, your Q will be of zero use to any other reader.  If you hadn't posted a bonus, I would have closed it as a Duplicate.

Comment: Then there is the problem that the Q doesn't contain a proper MCVE.  The code where the real problem is in a pastebin link.  That's a big " no no " on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look your Error Msg!this is a NullPointerException.  List is a null object! check you code

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.example.tilak.imusicplay.MusicService: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your application does not initialise `songs`.  (Sure, there is a `setSongs` method, but you don't call it!)

Solution: add code to initialize `songs` in the appropriate place.  That will fix *this* error ...

I strongly advise you to read the Question and Answers for:

- [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)